# Add logs to rules drools

Tags: logging, drools, rules, rule-engine

I have two drools files with the rules defined. I have consumers, who consume the rules, and I have 4 rules engine classes, which are the channel between consumers and the rules (these being four classes: rulesEngine, RulesSession, RulesStatefulSession and RulesStatelessSession). I wanted to put a logging mechanism here, to know what time a rule was triggered, and which consumer. What is the best way to do this? I didn't want to touch the code already developed, I just wanted to add new lines for this monitoring.

All help is welcome because I don't know how to add logs to rules.

Comment: You can add listeners. https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#engine-event-listeners-con_decision-engine

Comment: I've seen the listeners but I never know what to put in the drool file, the consumer and the rules engine, because they explain what to do, but not where to put it and how to interconnect things @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: The listener doesn't go in the drools file. You attach it to the session before you invoke it and as the Drools Engine goes through its lifecycle it will trigger the listener's methods. If you follow the link I posted the first code block in that section shows a simple example listener being attached to the session.

Comment: I've already been analyzing the link you sent, and it really contains a lot of information, making it difficult to collect only what is necessary. Can you put here the necessary code block to put in the session? In my session I have several methods, such as insert, executeRules and addGlobal. Will I have to add a new method? And I have four classes, one RulesStatelessSession and RulesStatelessSession that extend RulesSession and one RuleSession. Do I have to create the listener in the four classes? @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: You could, but I personally just define a class that implements the appropriate listener interface and implement the methods I need, and then new up instances as needed and attach the instances to the sessions. I'll add an answer later today.

Comment: Thank you! My goal is to create that listener and send the information (like hours, what rule, etc.) to an external file. Having the account your information, then it is best to even create a new class and then just instantiate it in the sessions. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas